# Can I set a Spring bean value using a path outside of WebContent directory?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jsf

I currently have a file, `{project-name}/WebContent/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xm`l, that sets a sub directory into a bean file for further use.

```
<bean ....>
<property ...>
<value>WEB-INF/utilities</value>
</property>
</bean>
```

Changes are being made to have these files normally located in this sub directory added to the Java resource folder when the war is build (done with the pom file). I have tried setting the bean to use this path, but failing when trying to access files inside of it.

```
<bean ....>
<property ...>
<value>{project-name}/Java Resources/src</value>
</property>
</bean>
```

Is there a better option to reference the project path so `applicationContext.xml` can have visibility to the source folder?

Can the pom declare an alternate destination for resource files when building? If I can have the pom set the files to `"WEB-INF/utilities"` instead of defaulting to `"Java Resources/src"` that should be able to resolve my issue.

I have read questions regarding accessing files from the java resource directory, but those solutions require implementing java classes to read values from the included files; not setting the actual path location in a bean for use by other beans. Not sure the benefit of having a new class just to retrieve a directory name.

Comment: you wanna access not compiled *.java file?

Comment: Its not a java file. It is any arbitrary file *.txt, *.properties, etc.Yes, I'm trying to access that file.

Comment: do you have the path of the file in system, like: `/tmp/test.txt` or `C:/tmp/test.txt`?

Comment: No. The files are contained within the project (project/src/main/resources/). When the war is built it will include those files and add them to the Java Resource folder of the war.

Comment: Sure you are using Spring MVC AND full JSF at the same time?

Comment: Are you trying to migrate your code base build to Maven?

Comment: This question is strictly related to calling a path outside of the `WebContent` folder. It is already a maven project. The `applicationContext.xml` sets up beans using files that were originally in a sub folder of the `WEB-INF`. Now it must do the same thing with the file being in the `src/Java Resources` folder of the project. The question is asking for ways to reach access that directory as a direct path name isn't working.